# Why my python newt/snack program has odd characters?

Tags: python, linux, character

I've got a Python program using newt/snack module, and it works fine in Fedora 17 official release.

I need to port the program into the **initrd ram disk**, that is, a Linux running with only **initrd/vmlinuz**, but without any other file systems or **squashfs** images. I select Fedora 17's **initrd.img** ram disk, 'cause it has built-in Python 2.7.3. What I need to do is adding newt/snack module and its dependencies.

I've added newt/newt-python from Fedora 17 official release. The program does run, but it has odd characters in the border. I think it's newt/snack related. Please help! Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image: Python newt/snack with odd characters]

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried so far?  In particular, could you add a [Short, Self-Contained, (Compilable) Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)? And that really means *just* the code that produces that text box and nothing else. It's near-impossible to figure out the error from what you've posted.  Btw, you might also have better luck posting to a forum/mailing list specifically focused on Linux development.

Comment: It looks like the console does not support the `curses` library...

Answer (score 4):

Thanks all for caring.

I've solved this problem. It's related to locale.

When I type "/usr/bin/locale" command, it shows that the locale is POSIX, which has less character set.

What I did to solve this problem includes:

1. Copy `/usr/share/i18n/*` *(in official Fedora 17 release)* to the corresponding position in the initrd ram disk.
2. Create directory `usr/lib/locale` in the initrd ram disk.
3. Add :

> /usr/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 && export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 && export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

command into the init script in the initrd ram disk. This command will set the system locale to `en_US.UTF-8`.

By doing these steps, the newt/snack border shows well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem with similar odd characters in the border.
I was using a PuTTY terminal. I fixed the issue by changing PuTTY setting:
    Settings > Window > Translation
    Choose character set UTF-8, and line drawing chars "Use Unicode..."